# jquery not registering clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="sortable-buttons">
 <ul>
  <li><a>Recent</a></li>
  <li><a>Popular</a></li>
  <li><a>Being Discussed</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Then the following jquery:

```
ListView = {
init: function () {
    s_listview = {
        sortButton: $(".sortable-buttons li a"),
    };
    this.bindUIActions();
},

bindUIActions: function () {
    s_listview.sortButton.each( function (e) {
       $(this).on('click', function (e) {
           ListView.highlightButton(e, this);
       });
    });

},

highlightButton: function(e, clicked) {
    alert();
    $(clicked).closest('li').addClass('active');
}
};
```

However. only the first click is registered.
only one alert is shown, the rest dont work

Comment: Here for every click on an `a`  the `alert` is shown ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6beo14zt/)). Either you should not see any alert (if you don't call `ListView.init();`)  or it should work for every click. Your described behavior indicates that you do something else at another place.

Comment: if you call ListView.init() this code should work

Comment: can't you bind on this `s_listview.sortButton` instead of looping through and using `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the the `ListView.init()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 ListView = {
    init: function () {
        s_listview = {
            sortButton: $(".sortable-buttons li a"),
        };
        this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions: function () {
        s_listview.sortButton.each( function (e) {
           $(this).on('click', function (e) {
               ListView.highlightButton(e, this);
           });
        });

    },

    highlightButton: function(e, clicked) {
        alert();
        $(clicked).closest('li').addClass('active');
    }
  };
  ListView.init();
})
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sortable-buttons">
 <ul>
  <li><a>Recent</a></li>
  <li><a>Popular</a></li>
  <li><a>Being Discussed</a></li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

`

Comment: If `ListView.init();` is not called then `[...]only the first click is registered. only one alert is shown, the rest dont work[...]` statement would not match, so even if calling `ListView.init();` might _solve_ the problem, there still must something be wrong in another part of that code, otherwise the description of the problem won't match,